# How to write a AWS lambda function with S3 and Slack integration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a use case where i want to invoke my lambda function whenever a object has been pushed in S3 and then push this notification to slack.

I know this is vague but how can i start doing so ? How can i basically achieve this ? I need to see the structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of resources available for both integrations (s3+lambda and lambda+slack) so if you can put these together you can make it work.

You can use S3 Event Notifications to trigger a lambda function directly:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Here are some blueprints to integrate lambda with slack:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-slack-integration-blueprints-for-aws-lambda/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 Event Notifications to trigger the lambda function.
In bucket's properties, create a new event notification for an event type of ***s3:ObjectCreated:Put*** and set the destination to a Lambda function.
Then for the lambda function, write a code either in Python or NodeJS (or whatever you like) and parse the received event and send it to Slack webhook URL.